# Form within another form HTML

Tags: php, html, forms

I have the code below, and need to somehow  make it work. I know that you are not allowed to submit one form inside the other, so I was wondering if there was a way around that.

```
 <form method="post" action="somepage.php"> 
<input name="textbox_question" type="text">

<!--and there is a lot more code for this form here --> 

       <form id="fileupload" action="upload_form/server/php/" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
                       <div>
                    <div class="span7"><strong>
                       <span class="btn btn-success fileinput-button">  Add files...
                      <input type="file" name="files[]" multiple>
                          </span>

                      </button>
                    <br></br>
                    </strong></div>
                  </div>
                  <!-- The loading indicator is shown during file processing -->
                  <div class="fileupload-loading"></div>
                  <br>
                  <!-- The table listing the files available for upload/download --> 
                  <table role="presentation" class="table table-striped">
                    <tbody class="files" data-toggle="modal-gallery" data-target="#modal-gallery">
                    </tbody>
                  </table>
                </form>

  <!--and there is a lot more code for this form here --> 
  </form>
```

Comment: What is the intended behavior of nested forms?

Comment: The way around would be to read the contents of your forms with JavaScript and send them using AJAX. But why would you need nested forms in the first place?

Comment: If I'm not mistaken, nested form tags are removed from the DOM entirely (not the contents, just the tag itself) and the behavior varies between browsers... I would advise finding another way to do this.

Comment: Well it is on an order form, and in the middle of the form is an area for users to upload files without refreshing the page and that requires a separate form.

Comment: @user1637291 I still don't see how this requires nesting one form within another.

Comment: @Tom because the upload code is within a form. That form has to go halfway down the page in the center of the other form. They are two different forms.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Put the inner form into a separate document and embed it with `iframe`.